# How to define custom property in Android

Tags: android, android-xml

I want to define a custom property in my Android App.

I have defined GifMovieView class, that extends View.

All 3 constructors call a init(AttributeSet attrs) method :

```
if (attrs != null) {
        String packageName = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android";
        mUrl = attrs.getAttributeValue(packageName, "url");
        Log.i("TAG_MIO", mUrl);
    }
```

Log.i throws an Exception, because mUrl is null.

This property is defined in mainActivity_layout.xml in this way:

```
 <com.example.propertyproject.GifMovieView
    android:id="@+id/my_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    gif:url="http://mygif.com/mygif.gif" />
```

url is always null...

Is package name wrong? Does packageName have to be changed?

TY in advance,

Adriano.

Answer (score 0):

`*_layout.xml` is used for defining the layout of your GUI, not for defining custom strings.

There is another place reserved for that, it is in `res/values/strings.xml`. If `strings.xml` doesn't exist, create it with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>    
  <string name="gif_url">http://mygif.com/mygif.gif</string>
</resources>
```

Then you can access it using

```
String url = R.string.gif_url;  // (it becomes a static final property)
```

Comment: I don't want to define a String: I only want to define a custom property for an instance that extends a View object.
For example, I can define a property with a boolean, or int, value.
But I don't know how to access to this property.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create attrs.xml file in values folder, It contain all your custom attributes

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="MyTextView">
        <attr name="font_name" format="string" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

1. Create styles.xml in values folder, It will contain your style for the specific component, Here I am taking example of Textview, I am going to font name attribute in TextView

```
<style name="Header_Text_Text1">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/text1_header_text</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">26px</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:padding">2dp</item>
        <item name="[YOUR PACKAGE NAME]:font_name">calibri</item>
    </style>
```

1. Let's create java file to consume our new attributed, I am going to extend Textview, create mytextview.java

`public class MyTextView extends TextView {`

```
public MyTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    if (isInEditMode())
        return;

    final TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.MusicTextView);
    final String ttfName = ta.getText(0).toString();
    Log.i("Font Name :" + ttfName);
    ta.recycle();
}
```

}

1. New we can use our new Textview named "MyTextview" in layout.

```
<YOUR PACKAGE NAME.MyTextView
        android:id="@+id/header_txtTitle"
        style="@style/Header_Text_Text1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/header_home"
        android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
        android:text="" />
```